# Call to undefined function Intervention\Image\Gd\imagecreatefromjpeg() Laravel 8 + Docker desktop 4.4.4

Tags: laravel-8, gd, docker-desktop, libjpeg, php-8

This is my docker file:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-buster

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    npm \
    nodejs \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd
```

but I have an error

> Call to undefined function Intervention\Image\Gd\imagecreatefromjpeg()

when i try to upload a jpg image.Even I change it to:

```
docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
```

but I have below error when I build and the above error in Laravel

> configure: error: unrecognized options: --with-freetype-dir,
> --with-jpeg-dir, --with-gd
> ------ failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y
> build-essential     git     curl     libpng-dev     libjpeg-dev
> libfreetype6-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     jpegoptim optipng
> pngquant gifsicle     libonig-dev     libxml2-dev     zip     sudo
> unzip     npm     nodejs     && docker-php-ext-configure gd
> --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd]: exit code: 1

how can I fix this?

Comment: The built-in GD function is just `\imagecreatefromjpeg()`; do you know where the `Intervention` namespace is supposed to be defined?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I fix it by enabling the GD lib,
here is my Dockerfile configs:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-buster

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libgd-dev \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    npm \
    nodejs

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd
```

Answer (score 0):

I was still getting the same error even after trying the accepted answer. What solved the error for me was changing the driver from GD to Imagick, which I found how to do in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70695556/19632250).

Add the following to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev
RUN pecl install imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-enable imagick
```

Add this line to the PHP code before calling functions from the Intervention/Image package (`Image::make`, etc.).

```
Image::configure(['driver' => 'imagick']);
```